# Missing data from a field in list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, workflow

I have a list on which OOB approval workflow is running. In the list there is a column which shows the workflow status such as "Pending", "In Progress", "Completed" etc.

Today I found out that the column is showing blank. It was previously showing "Completed" or "Pending" (depending on circumstances) for each item but now it is showing nothing and just blank. Why did it happen? And this is not the first time it has happened and last time it happened was more than 2, 3 months ago.

Any reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dam, you didnt set the auto function off...

There is a time to live on workflows that occures i think by default every 60 days... once it reaches 60 days its removed by a timer job. Its active by default as its auto cleaning after two months to save on server speed and resources. If you disable it than it would over time slow sharepoint down!

to sort it out, goto timer job list in central admin and disable 'Workflow Auto Cleanup' under job definitions.

Comment: Thanks for this info. Didn't know about this. Let me check that job.